# Ubuntu: Reset $PATH to factory default

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, path, reset

I just made a mistake when adding a directory to path, and executed

```
$ PATH=/path/to/my/directory/
```

instead of

```
$ PATH=/path/to/my/directory/:$PATH
```

Consequently, my `$PATH` variable now contains *only* my own directory, which is of course a problem. I don't know exactly what was in the path before, but if I can reset to factory default I can start from there and add things as I need them.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can, just *log out* and *relog in*.

Otherwise, you can start with

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

and add missing entries.

Comment: What about /bin?

Comment: This only works assuming that the contents you describe are in fact the default PATH value for the OP's login shell; this might not be the case depending on his/her setup (especially if the OP is not the admin on the system and is using, for example, a login shell on an ISP-provided terminal account).

Comment: @Matt seems that (almost) everything already is in `/usr/bin`

Comment: @Matt, I trimmed `/usr/games` out of my path and cut one item too many. `/bin` is the fallback folder in tha path.  Thx. I've corrected.  @Viktor, Agreed, I actually assumed a standard Ubuntu 10.10 installation from the tag and the level of difficulty of the question.

Answer (score 2):

From the bash(1) man page:

> When **bash** is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the **--login** option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

So, on your system, it's most likely that you just need to look at what the default PATH value is in /etc/profile, set that, and then build up based on what your own login/profile bash scripts do to PATH.

If you're not using bash(1) but some other shell, then use "man *thatShellName*" to find out what it's invocation behaviour is, and perform similar steps.

As a quick short-cut, in your current shell, (again, assuming you're using bash(1)), type "bash --login" to get a new, login shell process; then, save the value of path with

```
echo $PATH > /tmp/myPath.txt
```

then "exit" out of the login shell and type

```
export PATH=`cat /tmp/myPath.txt`
```

(note the use of back-ticks in that last expression).

Or if you're a terminal app that has copy/paste abilities, you can just "bash --login", and copy the PATH value to the clipboard, exit, and then "export PATH" and paste in the PATH value.

Comment: I believe Ubuntu comes with PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
inside /etc/environment.  I probably need to check that however ;-).  But I agree it's a more complex topic than it appears, with different circumstances having different answers.

Comment: @Alain, yes, thanks very much for the clarification; I'm working with another *nix distribution here, so I tried to be as portable as possible. Every *nix installation seems to have a slightly different way of setting up login shell characteristics. Typically, using the man pages for the shell you're using is the best way to start, but not always because local distributions might not take the time to provide localized versions of the man pages. 8(

Answer (score 1):

in terminal open the bashrc file

`gedit ~/.bashrc`

At the last line add

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$PATH
export PATH`

Then save the file.

To verify, open a new terminal and type:

`printenv`

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a new user and copy the `$PATH` entries from there.

Apart from that, on a Ubuntu server I found:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: Creating a new user would only work if the default shell for a new user is the same shell as the one the OP is using. Also, it has the overhead of creating a user, which the OP might not have permissions to do.

Comment: @Viktor, Agreed with all of this, but as there were no further informations given, I assumed a "normal" installation without modifications.